# An affine scheme is connected $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathcal O(X)\ne \{0\}\land $ only have trivial nilpotents

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

> Definition: An aﬃne scheme X is connected if:
>   $X\ne \emptyset$
>   If $X_1$, $X_2$ are open subschemes of $X$ such that $X_1 ∪X_2= X$ and $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset$, then $X_1$ or $X_2$ is empty.

I aim to prove that An affine scheme is connected $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathcal O(X)\ne \{0\}\land \mathcal O(X)$ only have trivial nilpotents, that is, no more nilpotent than $0,1$.

I have proved $X$  is connected $\Rightarrow \mathcal O(X)$ is nonzero and the only idempotent in it are $0$ and $1$. And stuck on the other direction.

Could someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Here $\mathcal O(X)$ denotes the function algebra.

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423623/show-that-a-ring-with-disconnected-spectrum-is-a-product-of-two-subrings), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326452/if-mathop-mathrmspeca-is-not-connected-then-there-is-a-nontrivial-idempot)

Comment: Contrary to what you seem to believe the empty set (with $\mathcal O(\emptyset)=\{0\}) $ is connected and the ring $\{0\} $ only has a trivial nilpotent. So in your equivalence you should delete the condition $\mathcal O(X)\ne \{0\}$

Answer (score 2):

It is basically trivial.

Assume that $X=specA$ is not connected, then there is open sets $U, V$, such that  $X=U\cup V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$. Let $f\in \mathcal{O}_X(X)=A$, such that $f|_U=1$ and $f|_V=0$. Then $f$ is idempotent, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please explain your notation? Is $f|_U$ meaning that the polynomial $f$ restricted to $U$? If so, I haven't seen such a thing... How does it defined and how does it work?

Comment: @PropositionX   I define $f$ to be   $f|_U=1$ and $f|_V=0$, which is of course a polynomial and lives in $A$.