# Ring of polynomials has zero divisors is equivalent to it being a direct product of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative, associative ring with unit, consider $R[x]$. Is it true that the following two statements are equivalent?
$$
R[x] \text{ is the direct product of rings}
$$

$$
R[x] \text{ has zero divisors}
$$

If it's a product of rings, then it's obvious that it has zero divisors, but I can't prove the other implication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Let $R=k[y]/(y^2)$ for $k$ a field. Then $R[x]\cong k[x,y]/(y^2)$ which has zero divisors but is not the direct product of rings since it has a unique minimal prime $(y)$.

Comment: Okay, that's good example, but i suppose this statement is true if $R$ is field?

Comment: @NeoFanatic Sure, but that is because in that case both statements are false anyway.

Comment: @NeoFanatic $R[x]$ is a direct product iff $R$ is, and $R[x]$ has zero divisors iff $R$ does, but there's a big difference between having zero-divisors and being a direct product. [Direct products have disconnected spectrum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326452/if-operatornamespec-a-is-not-connected-then-there-is-a-nontrivial-idempoten) while rings with zero divisors may be irreducible (hence connected) but not reduced, or reduced but not irreducible (and reducible may or may not be connected).