# Is "Zariski connected" equivalent to "ring connected"?

Tags: ring-theory, connectedness, zariski-topology

Let A be a ring, in class we defined the following two definitions of connected: 
A is Zariski connected if Spec A is connected with the Zariski topology. 
A is ring connected if
$$a+b=1, ab=0\Rightarrow a = 0, b = 1$$
(or $b=0, a=1$)
I want to know if these are equivalent with a proof or counter example. I have succeded in showing Zariski connected implies ring connected. But all atempts at the reverse are failing, and I don't know where to start searching for a counterexample.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find this definition?  I ask because normally "connected" is used to mean "directly irreducible" as in "no nontrivial idempotents" because it corresponds with the connectedness of $Spec(R)$.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/299785/29335) for example.  Your definition certainly implies that idempotents are trivial, but it's not clear to me that the converse is true.

Comment: @rschwieb I saw this in my rings and fields class in the exercise sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little thought, this does turn out to be equivalent to the definition of "connected" that I have seen, which is "no nontrivial idempotents."

It's known that $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is connected iff $R$ has no nontrivial idempotents (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299765/what-does-the-topology-on-operatornamespecr-tells-us-about-r/299785#299785)).

Certainly the condition you mention implies there are no nontrivial idempotents (just consider $e$ and $(1-e)$.)

Conversely: suppose that there are $a,b$ such that $a+b=1$ and $ab=0$ and there are only trivial idempotents.  If either one is zero we are done, so without loss of generality suppose both are nonzero.

The condition that $a+b=1$ tells us $(a)$ and $(b)$ are coprime ideals. As such, the Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that $(ab)=(a)(b)=(a)\cap (b)$ and that $R\cong R/(a)\times R/(b)$ as rings.  If we assumed that there are only trivial idempotents, one of these halves would have to be zero, for example, $(b)=R$, but that can't be the case since $b$ is clearly not a unit (it is a zero divisor.). Similarly $(a)= R$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Alternatively, if $a+b = 1$ and $ab = 0$ then $a = a(a+b) = a^2$ and similarly $b^2 = b$, so $a$ and $b$ are idempotents.

Comment: @DanielSchepler ah that's a clever way to do it too :)