# How to turn a topological space into a semi-decidable logic?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, logic

In two interesting posts([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31859/what-concept-does-an-open-set-axiomatise) and [here](http://xorshammer.com/2011/07/09/a-logical-interpretation-of-some-bits-of-topology/)),it is mentioned that "there is a close connection between semi-decidable logics and topological spaces"

Michael O’Connor wrote:

> In fact, given a topological space, you can form a semi-decidable logic by making a propositional symbol $P_U$ for each open set $U$ . You can then interpret all propositional formulas as open sets by interpreting $\lor$ as union and $\land$as intersection. Finally, take as a set of axioms the set of all statements $P \vdash Q$where the open set corresponding to $P$is a subset of the open set corresponding to $P$ . This set is closed under the inference rules given.
>
> You can also start with a semi-decidable logic and generate a topology; this is a form of Stone duality.  In general, if you start with a topological space, translate to a semi-decidable logic, then translate back, you might not get your original space back.  However, you will if the space you start with is sufficiently nice (e.g., Hausdorff).

**Question:** Could anyone give a concrete example of how this can be done? For example what's semidecidable logic of $\omega^{\omega}$ with a product topology? What is $P_U$, if $U = \{0\} \times \omega^{\omega}$?

Any reference on this topic is also welcome. In a comment,Peter Berry suggested "the book “Topology via Logic” by Stephen Vickers takes this approach". So I think this book must be a good reference on this problem, but I can't find the keyword semi-decidable in its index. This book can be found [here](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Topology_Via_Logic.html?id=VvCKDnCrZCgC) on googlebooks.

Comment: I've been investigating the same thing! It's a shame this question hasn't been answered. Have you found any other references regarding this topic?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since any activity on this, but I'll just leave this link as it may be of interest to others stumbling upon this post: [What concept does an open set axiomatise?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31859/what-concept-does-an-open-set-axiomatise)

Also for what it's worth, the word "semidecidable" does appear many times in the Vickers book, only without a hyphen...