# Why are continuous maps more important than open maps?

Tags: continuity, category-theory, soft-question, intuition

An open map between topological spaces is one that maps open sets to open sets. It says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps) that

> Although their definitions seem more natural, open and closed maps are much less important than continuous maps.

The usual "explanation" is that continuous functions are morphisms in *Top*, but why should that be the case? What does preserving pre-images have to do with being the "right" morphisms in a category? This also happens with concepts like measurability, where the "right" functions to look at are those where pre-images of measurable sets are measurable. I see no inconsistencies with defining morphisms to be e.g. open maps between objects in *Top* and something similar for the category of measurable sets, so why are these categories not as important? The morphisms here seem just as "structure-preserving" as the usual ones. Is there some deeper reason why it's the pre-images we should be looking at in both these cases (and more)?

Comment: My first thought is that the notion of continuity far predates the notion of a topological or metric space. It's simply the formalization of "not having jumps" for functions on the reals or for metric spaces, which is clearly quite physically important.

Comment: This kind of question has been asked a few times before. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823758/why-is-the-topological-definition-of-continuous-the-way-it-is), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22658/why-are-inverse-images-more-important-than-images-in-mathematics), and especially [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932942/why-are-continuous-functions-the-right-morphisms-between-topological-spaces)