# Intuition on open set

Tags: general-topology, intuition

I have some basic knowledge on topology. Currently my intuition on open set roughly comes from the concept of open ball in metric space, that is to say, an open set is 'a region around a certain point'. This intuition has been fine for me to continue my study, but I find it not satisfactory for some reasons.

The first reason is because of arbitrary union. The concept of continuity at a point $p$ in any analysis book is roughly like, for some region $V$ around $f(p)$ there exists a region $U$ around $p$, such that $f(U) \subseteq V$. If we replace the word 'region' with 'open set', it seems to be that the concept of open set fits here perfectly. However since open set allows arbitrary union, it's perfectly valid that an open set $U \ni p$ consists of two disconnected open sets that are far away in space. It feels weird that when we are talking about the contiunity at a specific point, we drag in some arbitrary region somewhere far away into our arguments. Say $(-1, 1) \cup (100, 101)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, when we consider continuity at $0$, we only should be taking $(-1, 1)$ into consideration, and it has nothing to do with $(100, 101)$. But since we are talk about open set in general, we have to take $(100, 101)$ implictly into our arguments. Since open set can be arbitrary union, it doesn't really fit into the idea of 'a region around some point', but continuity seems to me relies on this idea. It's great that open set formulation works (since $f(U_1) \subseteq f(U_1 \cup U_2) \subseteq V$), but I hope there's a better reconciliation between the concept of open set (with arbitrary union) and region around a point.

The second reason is just that if I think about open set as 'region around a point', I seem to be missing all the subtleties of openness, closedness and boundary. Because we can easily replace open set with closed set and say a closed set is also a 'region around a point', thus this idea is apparently too coarse. All these concepts are kind of interrelated, but I want to have a starting point in terms of the intuition. For example boundary point is considered as a point such that any region around it no matter how small will intersect with both $S$ and $S^C$. But this intuition still relies on the concept of open set, so to me it feels like to be begging the original question on the intuition of open set.

There're [some threads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31859/what-concept-does-an-open-set-axiomatise) explaining that an open set is actually a semi-decidable property. It feels like that direction is promising, but I don't see very clearly how that idea materialise under the interpretation of point space.

Are there better intuitions for open sets?

Comment: I don’t think your intuition is about open sets; your intuition of “region around a certain point” seems closer to the notion of *neighborhood of a point*. An open set is a set that is a neighborhood of all its points.

Comment: First off, I just read your "answer" on the Overflow thread, and I think you have a serious misunderstanding on the semi-decidability model. To be fair, the idea of parallel processability wasn't explained in the most illuminating way, but take some time to reread the material there. It will make more sense.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You're right. I'm asking about a better intuition on open set. I don't think open set as 'a neighborhood of all its points' is better as I explained in my first reason. (-1, 1) U (100, 101) doesn't feel to be a neighbourhood around 0 since (100, 101) is far away.

Comment: A neighborhood of $p$ is *any set* that **includes** “a region near $p$”, not merely a set where *everything* is “a region near $p$”.

Comment: @DonThousand I thought semi-decidability means if it's in the set I can compute in finite time that it's in the set. If it's not in the set then we might never know it's not in the set? Assume we can indeed run arbitrary number of procedures in parallel, then topology axioms do correspond to semi-decidability?

But after all my question is about the intuition of open set. So welcome to explain without the semi-decidability or illuminate on the connection between semi-decidable properties and point set space a bit more :)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/why-do-we-require-a-topological-space-to-be-closed-under-finite-intersection/4116#4116)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But isn't it a bit weird that when we talk about continuity at a local point, we would need to also refer to a 'neighborhood' that contains some place far far away?

Comment: No, because we require it to happen at *all* neighborhoods. If you ask who lives “near” me, then depending on your definition of “near” I may mention people who live a block away, or may two hours drive away. Look, you could think of an undefined concept of “close neighborhood” of a point, which is a bit nebulous but intuitively is not just things near by, but *only* things near by. Then a neighborhood is any set that includes a “close neighborhood”; and then an open set is any set that includes a neighborhood of all of its points.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for your answer, but I'm still not feeling convinced. In the example of continuity, the idea we want to convey is indeed that **all** of the **nearby** points will be mapped into a provided area in codomain. I feel a bit uncomfortable if every time when I think about open set, I have to consider something like 'this might not be a local region, it might contain some place far away'. This doesn't happen to continuity only, it seems that in a lot of definitions when we refer to open set, we're really thinking about some **local** space. E.g. a chart in manifold.

Comment: The open set formulation does work, but feels a bit magically (when an open set can contain some place far away). What I'm looking for is an intuitive explanation about why that works. Also I'd like to have intuition that captures the second point I made in my question.

Comment: You can define continuity in terms of a basis for a system of neighborhoods. It’s an equivalent formulation. You can define topology in terms of a system of neighborhods for each point. You can also define continuity in terms of special families of open sets (a basis, or even a subbasis). But ultimately, the reason you are having trouble is that you are focusing on **precisely the wrong thing**. “locality”, “far away”, etc. are metric concepts. Topology does *not* concern itself with that type of notion, **by design**. If you insist on trying to fit it into it, you get silliness. Well, yes.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's exactly my concern as well. I feel my intuition doesn't fit open set very well that's why I'm asking for a new and better intuition. But the thing is that it feels definitions like continuity does concern with locality, so how to reconcile it in the setting of topological space?

Comment: By forgetting your metric notion of “locality.” The locality that topology concerns itself with is precisely the locality of neighborhoods of a point, but that is the locality that you insist on rejecting because if it lives inside a metric space then it doesn’t reconcile with the **metric** notion of locality that you keep trying to bring to the party.

Comment: In my opinion, you're (partially; see below) asking the wrong question. Topology *isn't* just looking at generalizing our existing intuitions; rather, it's generalizing in a sort of opposite way, by looking at what mathematical "data" is really needed for the theorems those intuitions lead to. A big theme in topology, in fact, is that our old intuitions are actually *hindering* us by trapping us in an overly-specific context. We can characterize continuous maps in the context of metric spaces by just talking about open sets; what does that mean? (cont'd)

Comment: It *doesn't* mean that that new characterization should match our original intuitions about continuity; rather, it means that our original intuitions weren't really that fundamental. I think a key skill in mathematics is **the ability to become dissatisfied with your own intuition**; really wanting a new intuition is quite different than wanting to extend an old intuition. Now of course this isn't really that helpful for you; all I'm saying is that metric ideas aren't the right ones, but you're asking "Are there better intuitions for open sets?" This is **exactly** the right question. (cont'd)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's (in my opinion) also *really hard*, which is why these are comments as opposed to an answer. It's difficult for me to put into words how I think about topological spaces; semidecidability plays a role, but so do ideas about "closure" (we can describe topology in terms of closure operators rather than open sets!), and somehow this fits together well. For what it's worth, [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19152/why-is-a-topology-made-up-of-open-sets?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) might be helpful to you.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for your answer. I'm aware of the thread you refered as well as the idea you mentioned that topological space is a concise abstract formulation that is in some sense hard or inappropriate to have usual intuition on. A better intuition would still be helpful though :) I guess I will keep the question in the background for now.